# Did this hypnotist accidentally leave participants 'in a trance'?

Tags: hypnotism

Is this just a lazy publicity stunt (intended or otherwise)?

["Hypnotist's Mishap Leaves People In Trance" Via Sky News](http://news.sky.com/story/860603/hypnotists-mishap-leaves-people-in-trance)

I'm sceptical of hypnosis, but haven't seen anything definitive either way.

Comment: (Where's Chris Angel when you need him?)  ;-P

Comment: What's the claim that you are skeptical of? That three people stayed for ten minutes in a trance while people left the room?

Comment: That the show participants could be "left in a trance" at all. My assumption is that the hypnotist had an unfortunate accident, which left him out cold for a few minutes, and later decided that it would make for a good news piece and publicity for his show.

As much as I try, I can't find out a definitive answer for whether or not hypnotism is at all possible! Like I said, I'm sceptical, but I haven't seen anything that proves or disproves it - just what I see in clips and in news articles.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a "trance"?

Comment: Umm... Not really, as my definition might be different to Sky News'!

My assumption would be that they mean something along the lines of "an altered state of consciousness".